# Eliminar elementos repetidos

Tags: c++, array, eliminar-duplicados

Estoy aprendiendo a programar. En el curso nos dijeron que agreguemos un método para eliminar elementos repetidos.

He intentado varias formas pero no me funcionan. Se agradecería mucho más si me explican que método se puede usar si seria solo un método o varios.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
//variables globales

//-------------------------------------------------
int V[100];
int dim;

//*************************************************
void adicionar (int x)
{
    if(dim<100)
    {
        V[dim] = x;
        dim++;
    }
}
void adicionarElementos()
{
    int x;
    int n=0;
    cout<<"Cuantos Datos Desea Ingresar ?:";
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Ingrese un numero:";
        cin>>x;
        adicionar(x);
    }
}
int MayorNumero()
{
    int Mayor=V[0];
    for (int i=0;i<=dim;i++)
    {
        if(V[i]>Mayor)
        {
           Mayor=V[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<"El numero Mayor es:"<<Mayor<<endl;
    return Mayor;
}
void invertir()
{
    int aux;
    for(int i=0;i<dim/2;i++)
    {
        aux=V[i];
        V[i]=V[dim-1-i];
        V[dim-1-i]=aux;
    }
}

void OrdenarBurbuja()
{
    for (int j=0;j<dim-1;j++)
 {
    for(int i=0;i<dim-1-j;i++)
   {
        if(V[i]>V[i+1])
        {
        int aux=V[i];
        V[i]=V[i+1];
        V[i+1]=aux;
        }
   }
 }
}
    
void OrdenarInsercion()
{
    for(int i=1;i<dim;i++)
    {
        int j=i;int aux=V[i];
        while(j>0 && aux<V[j-1])
        {
            V[j]=V[j-1];
            j--;
        }
        V[j]=aux;
    }
}

void OrdenarSeleccion()
{
    for(int i=0;i<dim-1;i++)
    {
        int menor=V[i];
        int posMenor=i;
        for(int j=i;j<dim;j++)
        {
            if(V[j]<menor)
            {
                menor=V[j];
                posMenor=j;
            }
        }
        int aux=V[i];
        V[i]=V[posMenor];
        V[posMenor]=aux;
    }
}
void EliminarPos(int p)
{
    if (p>=0&&p<dim)
    {
        for (int i=p;i<dim-1;i++)
        {
            V[i]=V[i+1];
        }
        dim--;
    }
}
void EliminarElementos (int x)
{
    int i =0;
    while(i<dim)
    {
        if(V[i]==x)
        {
            EliminarPos(i);
        }
        else i++;
    }
}
int ContarNumeros(int x)
{
    int c=0;
    for (int i=0;i<dim;i++)
    {
        if(V[i]==x)
        {
            c++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

void mostrar()
{
    for(int i=0;i<dim;i++)
    {
        cout<<V[i]<<" , ";
    }
}
void procesar1()
{
    adicionarElementos();
}
void procesar2()
{
    mostrar();
}
void procesar3()
{
    MayorNumero();
}
void procesar4()
{
    invertir();
}
void procesar5()
{
    OrdenarBurbuja();
}
void procesar6()
{
    OrdenarInsercion();
}
void procesar7()
{
    OrdenarSeleccion();
}
void procesar8()
{
    cout<<"Que Posicion desea eliminar";
    int p;
    cin>>p;
    EliminarPos(p);
    mostrar();
}
void procesar9()
{
    cout<<"Nro a Eliminar?:";
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    EliminarElementos(x);
    mostrar();
}
void procesar10()
{
    cout<<"Numero a buscar"<<endl;
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    int m=ContarNumeros(x);
    cout<<"Total Ocurrencias:"<<m<<endl;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    dim = 0;
    int opcion = 0;
    do
    {
        cout<<"1.- Adicionar Elmentos"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.- Mostrar"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.- Mayor"<<endl;
        cout<<"4.- Invertir"<<endl;
        cout<<"5.- Ordenar Burbuja"<<endl;
        cout<<"6.- Ordenar Insercion"<<endl;
        cout<<"7.- Ordenar Seleccion"<<endl;
        cout<<"8.- Eliminar Posicion"<<endl;
        cout<<"9.- Eliminar Elementos"<<endl;
        cout<<"10.- Contar Numeros"<<endl;
        cout<<"11.- Salir"<<endl;
        cout<<"Ingrese su opcion...."<<endl;
        cin>>opcion;
        switch(opcion)
        {
        case 1: procesar1();break;
        case 2: procesar2();break;
        case 3: procesar3();break;
        case 4: procesar4();break;
        case 5: procesar5();break;
        case 6: procesar6();break;
        case 7: procesar7();break;
        case 8: procesar8();break;
        case 9: procesar9();break;
        case 10: procesar10();break;
        
        }
        system ("pause");
    } while(opcion!=11);
    
    return 0;
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor no utilices el formato de snippet de HTML/CSS/Javascript con un lenguaje que no sea ninguno de esos. Funciona solo con dichos lenguajes y si intentas ejecutarlo con otro obtendrás errores.

Comment: Dices que has intentado varias formas, pero no veo ninguno de esos intentos. Por favor ¿Podrías compartir tus intentos para el algoritmo de eliminación de números repetidos y quitar de tu ejemplo todo lo que no tiene nada que ver con ello?